# Alternative definitions of regular conditional distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, Durrett (Probability: Theory and Examples, $\S 4.1.3$) defines the regular conditional distribution of a random variable $X$ given a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ by requiring that the map $\mu(\cdot,\omega)$ is a probability measure on the state space only for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ (that is, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.); Billingsley (Probability and Measure, Theorem $33.3$) instead requires that it is so for every $\omega\in\Omega$. Is there any difference in these two approaches, or are they equivalent in terms of the theories that derive from them? Thanks for any explanation you can provide.

Comment: In the second kind do you still get a finite measure? If so can you not somehow use the characterisation via $\pi$-System by checking that $\mu(\cdot,\omega) = \tilde{\mu}(\cdot, \omega)$, this seems to give $\mathbb P$-a.s. the same regular conditional distribution, which seems to enough for almost everything, no?

Comment: Clearly if we consider the first definition and the second, they agree almost surely. I believe the second is just obtained from the first, by just defining arbitrarily for all $\omega$ in the exceptional negligible set on which they differ, $\mu((-\infty, x),\omega)=F(x)$ for some cdf $F(x)$, which has nothing to do with $X$, and then using the $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem to have a well defined measure $\mu(\cdot, \omega)$ on this negligible set. The question is: why bother? What are the benefits of doing so? The subsequent theory seems to do just fine with the first approach.